# PHP Session cookie not saving, unable to access session data

Tags: php, session

I've this little problem: PHP is not saving the cookie to my (cookie allowing) browser, other sites are fine but this one fails to save the session id in the cookie, ergo an inability to access necessary data.
The index page does a

```
require("includes/functions.php");
```

which successfully requires my functions file:

```
session_name('login');
// Starting the session
$expiretime = 60*60*24;
session_set_cookie_params($expiretime);
// Making the cookie live for 1 day
session_start();
```

However, the login cookie is not saving (checked via Firebug) and I've no reason why. Thanks for the help

Comment: Check the other cookie parameters, especially the domain.

Comment: What does the cookie header look like?

Comment: There is no cookie present after that code is executed, that is the problem. The session file is in its appropriate directory but there is no SID cookie for it to reference to.

Comment: As I already said, try setting the domain to your current domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying the session cookie parameters to make sure they are ok by running after session_start:

```
var_dump(session_get_cookie_params());
```

If path (or domain) doesn't match the prefix of your web app path, then you might have to set it explicitly:

```
session_set_cookie_params($expiretime, '/');
```

or

```
session_set_cookie_params($expiretime, '/myapp/');
```